# How to get the block number?

Tags: javascript

```
var test = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();
```

I copied this code from the docs but when I call it I get this error:

```
TypeError: e is not a function
```

Anyone know what might be causing this?

I'm able to do

```
userAccountAddress = await web3.eth.accounts[0];
```

no problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Most `web3.js` objects allow a callback as the last parameter, as well as returning promises to chain functions.

The error `TypeError: e is not a function` means it is missing callback function.

In your case `await` must work out of box, I'm thinking you're use it wrong, here is an example from documentation [`getBlockNumber()`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html?highlight=blocknumber#getblocknumber):

```
web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then(console.log);
> 2744
```

If you still want use `await` you must use it right, with `async` keyword.

```
(async ()=> { await web3.eth.getBlockNumber(console.log) })()
> 2744
```

<sub>Looks ugly ya? That's javascript my friend.</sub>

<sub>Tip:
If you want the blocknumber you can use `web3.eth.blockNumber`.</sub>

Comment: Please make the tip larger, it works great in `truffle develop`!

Answer (score 2):

[In the interactive REPL mode](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-use-the-nodejs-repl) this is not working (await is only valid in async function)

```
userAccountAddress = await web3.eth.accounts[0];
```

If you just want to play around in interactive mode you could do:

```
> let n;
undefined
> n = web3.eth.getBlockNumber();
Promise { <pending> }
> n
Promise { 392629 }
>
```

Here i did not handle the promise, just waited for it to resolve.

If it should be for actual code you have to write an async function and await inside, just as @Зелёный said.